# Fluent NHibernate Configuration with MySQL

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

hi guys i am using Fluent NHibernate with MySQL but i can't really access the database i get error in the Configuration

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var mysqlconf = MySQLConfiguration.Standard
        .ConnectionString(c => c.Is("Server=localhost;Database=db;User=root;Password=boot;"));

    return Fluently.Configure().Database(mysqlconf).Mappings(m =>
                                                             m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>()).
        BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Please help me configuring my code to connect to my database

The Error
`An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.`

Comment: And the error is what exactly?

Comment: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

Comment: Please check the InnerException property of exception

Comment: The following types may not be used as proxies:
NHibernate.Tutorial.Entities.Product: method set_Id should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
NHibernate.Tutorial.Entities.Product: method set_StoresStockedIn should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
NHibernate.Tutorial.Entities.Store: method AddProduct should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
NHibernate.Tutorial.Entities.Store: method AddEmployee should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'

Comment: Please check if your properties in model are virtual

Comment: I have fixed them but it came with another error

Comment: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Comment: I Hope i find any help for the damn error above

Comment: Sorry but i need heko why i am getting Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Comment: Have you installed a MySQL Connector for .NET? If not, you probably have to do so. You can find one here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: i have installed that but it does not appear in visual studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed the connecting problem for Visual Studio 2012 using the mysql.Net connector 6.6.2

here is the download link
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.6.2.msi